# Inserting a TIME value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Let say we have

```
 CREATE TABLE event (
      eid  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
      start_time  TIME NOT NULL,
      duration    TIME NOT NULL,
      description VARCHAR(50),
      pid         VARCHAR(50),
      FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES person(pid) );
```

if I want to set the time for `start_time` as 2:00 pm

my question is that start_time variable should be Int only?

then I can not write the pm

or it should be some type of string? to write the full '2:00 pm'

thank you

Comment: You mean you want to insert records whose `start_time < 2:00pm`.??

Comment: The `TIME` data type is not meant to be used for *time of day* values. Rather, it is an amount of time in hours, minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an alternative, start_time field could store "14:00:00" directly.

e.g

```
UPDATE TABLE SET start_time= STR_TO_DATE('14:00:00', '%k:%i:%s');
```

while you retrieve the data, the sql may look like below:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(start_time, '%r') FROM TABLE
```

However, it is still a little different from your expectation, the result will be 2:00:00 PM

Answer (score 0):

first of all change the start_time field data type from time to varchar because you are going to store the 2:00 pm and pm keyword is string so string type store in varchar OR char and

instead of

```
start_time TIME NOT NULL
```

code this

```
start_time VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "2:00 PM",
```

if you want to use time data type in start_time field code this

```
start_time TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT "2:00",
```

remove PM keyword

Answer (score 0):

Just try it.

```
CREATE TABLE event (
      eid  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
      start_time  TIME NOT NULL default "2:00",
      duration    TIME NOT NULL,
      description VARCHAR(50),
      pid         VARCHAR(50),
      FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES person(pid) );
```

It will insert default `"2:00"` value to `start_time` if `start_time` is null.